# Codeigniter - Combining Three tables into correct view format

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Completely confused on how to achieve something - I have three tables;

- Orders
- Items
- Products

The orders table contains the details of an order, the items table contains a product id number and an order id number, and the products table contains all the product details.

What I'm trying to do is have a "My orders" page, where you can view all your past orders, and what i would like is to be able to have the following structure...

**ORDERS**

**ORDER NUMBER 1**

- Example order item
- Second example order item
- Third example order item

**ORDER NUMBER 2**

- Example order item
- Second example order item
- Third example order item

**ORDER NUMBER 3**

- Example order item
- Second example order item
- Third example order item

Now i can easily list all the orders, and i can list all the items on a particular order, but I'm lost on how to merge these three tables in a way i can list them in the above format, i assume i can JOIN on all three, but i can't get them to output in anywhere near the correct way.

Does anybody know a good way of doing this? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: A good way of doing this is implementing Datamapper with Codeigniter so you can set up your relationships quite easy. That way you could create a order object and get the connected data. Otherwise write your own SQL query, indeed, with some joins.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll certainly look into Datamapper, i've not used ORM yet so have a lot of learning to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a joined query to get all orders with their items

```
/* raw sql query */
SELECT o.*,p.*,o.id AS order_id,p.id AS product_id
FROM  Orders o 
LEFT JOIN Items i ON (o.id=i.order_id)
LEFT JOIN Products p ON(p.id = i.product_id) 
ORDER BY order_id
```

Create a function in your  model and run below query

```
/* Using Active record */

$orders=$this->db->select('o.*,p.*,o.id AS order_id,p.id AS product_id')
                ->from(' Orders o ')
                ->join(' Items i','o.id=i.order_id','LEFT')
                ->join(' Products p','p.id = i.product_id','LEFT')
                ->order_by('order_id')
                ->get()
                ->result();
```

Get your results from model in controller and then pass it to view,in view you can loop over your query records as

```
$currentParent = false;
foreach ($orders as $o) {
    if ($currentParent != $o->order_id) {
        echo '<h1>ORDER NUMBER ' . $o->order_id . '</h1>';
        $currentParent = $o->order_id;
    }
    echo '<p>' . htmlentities($o->product_name) . '</p>';
}
```

This will output as

```
<h1>ORDER NUMBER 1</h1>
    <p>product 1</p>
    <p>product 2</p>
<h1>ORDER NUMBER 2</h1>
    <p> product 3</p>
```

If you have different html structure change it accordingly i have provided above example using heading and paragraph tag

**Edit** for using list tags in your you can do so

```
echo '<ul><li>';
$currentParent = false;
foreach ($orders as $o) {
    if ($currentParent != $o->order_id) {
        if ($currentParent != false) {
            echo '</ul></li><li>';
        }
        echo '<h1>ORDER NUMBER ' . $o->order_id . '</h1><ul>';
        $currentParent = $o->order_id;
    }
    echo '<li>' . htmlentities($o->product_name) . '</li>';
}
echo '</li></ul>';
```

This will output as

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h1>ORDER NUMBER 1</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><p>product 1</p></li>
            <li><p>product 2</p></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h1>ORDER NUMBER 2</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><p> product 3</p></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic! Thanks so so much for this, really helped me understand joining a lot more and the logic behind displaying it! I don't suppose i can be really cheeky and ask if you know how to get the HTML output to be wrapped in an element? I want the orders in a LI element, but can't figure out a way of opening/closing the tags within the loop properly! Thanks again, really grateful :-)

Comment: @CarlBembridge i have added example using list tags see if it works

Comment: Perfect - You are an absolute star. Again, thanks so much for your time and help, it's really appreciated.