# codeigniter pass parameters to controller

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to pass parameters from view to controller..

**controller**

```
<?php

class Site2 extends CI_Controller{

    function index(){
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->home();
    }

    public function getBranchDetails($b_id){
        $this->load->model('bank_account_model');
        $data['rresults'] = $this->bank_account_model->getAccount($b_id);
        $this->load->view('view_nav',$data);
    }

    public function home(){
        $this->load->model('get_company_model');
        $this->load->model('bank_account_model');
        $data['results'] = $this->get_company_model->get_All();
        //$data['site2']=$this; 
        $this->load->view('view_header');
        $this->load->view('view_nav',$data);
        $this->load->view('view_content');
        $this->load->view('view_footer');
    }
public function company_details($id){
        $this->load->model('company_detail_model');
        $data['company_result'] = $this->company_detail_model->getRecords($id);
        $this->load->model('get_company_model');
        $data['results'] = $this->get_company_model->get_All();
        $this->load->view('view_header');
        $this->load->view('view_nav',$data);
        $this->load->view('company_details',$data);
        $this->load->view('view_footer');
    }
```

**view**

```
<?php
    foreach($results as $row):
    ?>
    <div>
        <ol class="tree">
    <li>
        <label for="folder1"><a href="<?php echo site_url('site2/company_details/'.$row->id.''); ?>"><?=$row->name?></label></a> <input type="checkbox"  id="folder1" /> 
        <ol>
        <?php
        //here need to pass is ($row->id);
        foreach($myresult as $row2):
        ?>
            <li>
                <label for="subfolder1"><a href="#"><?=$row2->name?></a></label> <input type="checkbox" id="subfolder1" /> 

            </li>
            <?php
            endforeach;
            ?>
        </ol>
    </li>       
</ol>
    </div>

    <?php
    endforeach;
    ?>
```

in the view inside the first foreach loop I need to pass $row->id to the controller function company_details as a parameter.(purpose of this code is get first company ids from DB and then need to get branches according to the company id.)

Answer (score 1):

it's working 100%

**controller**

```
<?php

class Site2 extends CI_Controller{

    function index(){
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->home();
    }

    public function home(){
        $this->load->model('get_company_model');
        $this->load->model('bank_account_model');
        $data['results_company'] = $this->get_company_model->get_All();
        $data['results_branch'] = $this->get_company_model->get_branch();
        $data['results_banks'] = $this->get_company_model->get_banks();
        $this->load->view('view_header');
        $this->load->view('view_nav',$data);
        //$this->load->view('view_nav',$data_branch);
        $this->load->view('view_content');
        $this->load->view('view_footer');
        //$this->load->view('check',$data);
    }
```

**view**

```
 <?php    foreach($results_company as $row):  ?>

        <ol class="tree">
    <li>
        <label for="folder1"><a href="<?php echo site_url('site2/company_details/'.$row->id.''); ?>"><?php echo $row->name; ?></label></a> <input type="checkbox"  id="folder1" /> 
        <ol>
                <?php    foreach($results_branch as $row_branch): $count; ?>
                                    <?php 

                                    if($row_branch->companyid == $row->id){?>
                                        <li><label for="subfolder1"><a href="<?php echo site_url('site2/company_details/'.$row->id.''); ?>"><?php echo $row_branch->name; ?></a></label> <input type="checkbox" id="subfolder1" />

                                            <ol>

                                                    <?php    foreach($results_banks as $row_bank): $count2; ?>
                                                    <?php 

                                                    if($row_bank->branch_id == $row_branch->id){?>
                                                    <li><label for="childfolder1"><a href="<?php echo site_url('site2/company_details/'.$row_bank->branch_id.''); ?>"><?php echo $row_bank->bank;  ?></a></label> <input type="checkbox" id="subfolder1" /></li>
                                                    <?php } ?>

                                                    <?php   endforeach; ?>

                                            </ol>

                                    <?php } ?>
                </li>
                                    <?php   endforeach; ?>



        </ol>
    </li>       
</ol>


    <?php
    endforeach;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Organize your data in controller and pass it to view

```
public function home()
{
    $this->load->model('get_company_model');
    $this->load->model('bank_account_model');
    $data['rresults'] = $this->bank_account_model->getAccount($b_id);
    $results = $this->get_company_model->get_All();
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        $row->branches = $this->your_branch_model->getAllBranchesOfCompany($row->id);
    }
    $data['results'] = $results;
    $this->load->view('view_header');
    $this->load->view('view_nav', $data);
    $this->load->view('view_content');
    $this->load->view('view_footer');
}
```

And in view loop over each company data and on its branches index

```
<?php foreach ($results as $row):?>
    <div>
        <ol class="tree">
            <li>
                <label for="folder1"><a
                        href="<?php echo site_url('site2/company_details/' . $row->id . ''); ?>"><?= $row->name ?>
                </label></a> <input type="checkbox" id="folder1"/>
                <ol>
                    <?php
                    foreach ($row->branches as $row2):
                        ?>
                        <li>
                            <label for="subfolder1"><a href="#"><?= $row2->name ?></a></label> <input type="checkbox"id="subfolder1"/>
                        </li>
                    <?php
                    endforeach;
                    ?>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
<?php
endforeach;
?>
```

Another approach would be is use joined query for company and branches order data by company id and the loop through results  and display company name once for all of its branches for reference see [*Combining Three tables into correct view format*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23243273/codeigniter-combining-three-tables-into-correct-view-format/23243935#23243935)